# Scala Slick - Omit ID column (Auto_Increment)

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I have learned Scala, Slick, Akka for 2 months and I got a problem when doing a project of Akka...

```
// This case class is to use for parsing data from request
// case class UserTransaction(sender: String, recipient: String, amount: Int)

//This one is to use for reflecting database
case class UserTransactionDB(sender: String, recipient: String, amount: Int, id: Int)

class UserTransactionModelDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserTransactionDB](tag, "usertransaction")
{
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def sender = column[String]("sender")
    def recipient = column[String]("recipient")

    def amount = column[Int]("amount")

    override def * =

        (sender, recipient, amount, id) <> (UserTransactionDB.tupled, UserTransactionDB.unapply)

}
```

I want to send a POST request (Json) to Akka like this :

```
{"sender" : "S" , "recipient" : "R", "amount" : 100}
```

Now, I want to use just only one case class UserTransaction (without "id" field in UserTransactionDB) not only to reflect the database and but also to parse data from request.  Is this possible ?

Thank you and sorry for my English !

Comment: What json library are you using? I'm assuming `spray-json`... in that case you could provide a spray-json serializer that gets rid of the `id` field.

Comment: @mfirry Yes, I'm using jsonFormat4(UserTransactionDB.apply)

Comment: @mfirry Did you mean this one ? https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types

Comment: Thanks man, I did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a custom format... something along these lines:

```
case class UserTransactionDB(sender: String, recipient: String, amount: Int, id: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object UserTransactionJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[UserTransactionDB] {
    def write(c: UserTransactionDB) =
      JsArray(JsString(c.sender), JsString(c.recipient), JsNumber(c.amount))

    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsArray(Vector(JsString(sender), JsString(recipient), JsNumber(amount))) =>
        new UserTransactionDB(sender, recipient, amount.toInt)
      case _ => deserializationError("UserTransactionDB expected")
    }
  }
}
```